# How to create Team of Users model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to implement team model in Django.

What i want:

- User can be a member of multiple Teams
- Team can have multiple Users
- Team Member can be assigned to multiple categories
- Category can be assigned to multiple Team Members

I thought i could achieve it like this:

```
class System(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    #User can own multiple systems
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 250)


class Team(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a team
    """
    #Each system can have only one team, possibility of changing in the future
    system = models.OneToOneField(System)
    ...
    ...


class TeamMember(models.Model):
    """
    Bounds user to team
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    #Teams can have multiple team members, team member can be in multiple teams
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

But the longer i think about it, the more concerned i become if it can be done like that.

I have trouble with imagining how i would perform queries like: get all members of the team, get all teams that user belongs to, get categories that user is assigned to, get users that are assigned to categories.

Also i don't know if there is some kind of mistake in my code(thinking).

I know that there probably is some pre-baked solution, but I'd really like to do this on my own.

Comment: ok, so where is the category model?

Comment: @e4c5 To be honest i didn't implement category model yet, but lets just say it has name attribute in it, i will update my question in a second

Comment: I don't really see (based on your current models) why you need two models for System and Team.

Comment: @e4c5 You are absolutely right. I'm doing it this way right now, because i haven't decided yet if i want to implement functionality which would allow teams to be shared between chosen systems. If i decide to implement this functionality in the future, it will be just faster to only tweak Team model.

Comment: Honestly, your code looks perfectly fine - the System/Team duo may be a bit redundant, but I have a similar layout that works well (no headaches, Django's ORM makes life very easy)

Comment: how did you realize that? can you share your code, i have similar project